# How to generate and integrate own constructor in netbeans IDE for java

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Most of the IDE gives some templates or insert code options. In netbeans IDE option like "right click in any java source page" then "insert code or (**alt+insert**)" then we can choose like "constructor","getter setter method" or "tostring method"...etc and if
a user does not fulfill it's requirement. For example my requirement is like generated constructor, it's data member must be final or if i want to add some extra code at the generation time. i was going through following steps below

1. File -> New Project -> NetBeans Modules -> Module
2. New -> Other -> Module Development -> Code Generator.

it is available in this [link](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/71/nbm-code-generator.html).

Then run the project. It will open a new netbeans window -->new project-->java application --> create a classfile--> right click on page --> it will show new option like sample generator. Then will generate a method. 
So my requirement is when i click sample generator, it will generate a constructor according to my specification and requirement.

let me show you what i am getting. some screen shoot.

First:

[image: first,]

Second:

[image: second]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

A little difficult to follow what you are asking but if I understand you correctly you are asking how to create a custom template file for Netbeans?

There is a tutorial [here](https://netbeans.org/competition/win-with-netbeans/customize-java-template.html) that describes how to do that. It may be a little out of date though but hopefully close enough to the version of Netbeans you are using.

Comment: question can not be an answer

Comment: It's not a question alone. It gives a link to to a potential answer.

Comment: But the question already mentions that the template for constructors can not be customized

Comment: And as I stated 'A little difficult to follow what you are asking'. Plus I don't see in the question where it states in clear English that the constructor cannot be customised. Not sure why someone felt the need to downvote an attempt to provide a *possible* solution but I'm sure it made them feel better :-)

Comment: @Kerry you are sharing a tutorial link. Is it working for netbeans 8.2 ?